# Can't connect to Google Fitness API on WearOS

Tags: android, google-fit, android-wear-2.0, wearables

I have a problem connecting to the Google Fitness API from a WearOS device.
I want to use the watch to record heart rate to Google Fit. 
I think I have some problem with permissions:

- I build a FitnessOptions object, listing required datatypes. - `onCreate()`

  ```
  fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
      .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
      .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
      .build();
  ```
- I request permissions if needed, otherwise try to connect - `onResume()`

  ```
  if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Will request permissions.");
      GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
              this, // your activity
              GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
              GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
              fitnessOptions);
  } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Will access google fit.");
      accessGoogleFit();
  }
  ```

And here I have a problem: `GoogleSignIn` starts an activity and asks me to log in, as expected. I choose account, which ends log in activity and resumes my activity. And I still don't have permissions, because it prompts me again to sign in.

In my manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```

I use a similar process on phone and it works.
Both apps (mobile and wear) are registered in the Google API Console, using the same OAuth2 credentials (is that a problem?).

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the reason it didn't sign in.
Request code has to be the same in both apps - on phone and on watch, probably because they are in the same package and both requests were same.

So now I can sign in.